# Disable Garbage Collection?

Tags: optimization, server-load, 500-internal-error

I have a WP site which creates 500's errors for about 2% of Apache requests (mostly bots and crawlers). I'm not able to stack trace most of those requests with 500's neither to PHP or MySQL errors as well Apache error logs.

Apache access log example for crawlers:

```
41.79.186.247 - - [06/Oct/2015:11:23:49 -0400] "GET /international-chamber-of-commerce-icc-ud-754/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://www.bing.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
54.193.63.98 - - [06/Oct/2015:11:29:05 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "webmon-webagent v1.3"
199.167.17.37 - - [06/Oct/2015:11:39:23 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Anturis Agent)"
```

Is it good idea to disable a garbage collection (`gc_disable()`) for the whole WP site to prevent any memory leak caused by a theme or plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling garbage collection only means that what ever memory is being leaked will reamain leaked and there will be no effort to reclaim it.

To fix 500 problems you need to check the actual errors reported at the php error log.

Comment: The problem is that there are no corresponding errors for that 500's error timestamp (or even close to it) at the PHP error log or MySQL error log. 

It looks like a crawler or bot is visiting a site/page, getting 500 but there is no time out or any other error at the PHP error log neither connection or query issues at the MySQL error log.

Comment: then the 500 is most likely a problem at the webserver. have you tried to check error log at that level?

Comment: You mean Apache `access.log`?

Comment: yes, but its error logs

Comment: I have checked error logs and nothing there for related timestamp and source IP. Please check update OP for examples

Comment: then I would assume it is a plugin that does it, but anyway this get to out of the original scope of the question and server errors type of question are off-topic since it is hard to do more then guessing without access to the server